# Creating a custom helper in own package in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I am writing a new composer package to be used in laravel, in which I want to define my own helper function (the helper is defined in my own module, not in the laravel, but to be used by laravel - see the `helpers.php` in the tree below).

This is the `packages` folder **tree** of my module in the root of a fresh laravel project:

```
└───majidalaeinia
    └───favicon
        │   composer.json
        │
        ├───src
        │   │   FaviconServiceProvider.php
        │   │
        │   ├───app
        │   │       helpers.php
        │   │
        │   └───routes
        │           web.php
        │
        └───vendor
            │   autoload.php
            │
            └───composer
                    autoload_classmap.php
                    autoload_files.php
                    autoload_namespaces.php
                    autoload_psr4.php
                    autoload_real.php
                    autoload_static.php
                    ClassLoader.php
                    installed.json
                    LICENSE
```

Here is the `majidalaeinia/favicon/composer.json` content:

```
{
    "name": "majidalaeinia/favicon",
    "description": "This is an educational package on favicon.",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Majid Alaeinia",
            "email": "alaeinia.majid@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {},
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "majidalaeinia\\favicon\\": "src/"
        },
        "files": [
            "src/app/helpers.php"
        ]
    }
}
```

And here is the `composer.json` of the laravel project itself:

```
// ...
"autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/",
            "majidalaeinia\\favicon\\": "packages/majidalaeinia/favicon/src"
        }
    },
// ...
```

I have defined a helper in `majidalaeinia/favicon/src/app/helpers.php` and have tried `composer dumpautoload` command on laravel route and my own project and get no error, but can not see the result of my helper which is a simple `dd()` right now.

I get this error:

> Call to undefined function testtt() (View: D:\projects\favicon\resources\views\welcome.blade.php)

What can I do to use my custom helper in my module in laravel project?

Comment: When you `dumpautoload` does composer give you any errors? One thing to try is to delete the composer.lock file and run `composer install` again and see if your helper module gets brought in. This should rebuild everything missing in your `vendor` directory.

Comment: @RyanNerd No errors, runs successfully.

Comment: What happens if you call your function with the complete namespace to `\majidalaeinia\favicon\testtt()`?

Comment: @mdexp I have tried that already, returns `Call to undefined function majidalaeinia\favicon\testtt() (View: D:\projects\favicon\resources\views\welcome.blade.php)`.

Comment: Based on your psr-4 I think you should use this path: `packages/majidalaeinia/favicon/src/app/helpers.php` or `majidalaeinia/favicon/src/app/helpers.php`

Comment: Did you also try to add the namespace to the helpers.php as well before doing composer dump-autoload?

Comment: @AH.Pooladvand Still getting the same error.

Comment: @mdexp Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could not solve it by composer independently and used my package service provider.
I added this code to the `boot()` method of my `FaviconServiceProvider` and it works now:

```php
if (File::exists(__DIR__ . '\app\helpers.php')) {
            require __DIR__ . '\app\helpers.php';
        }
```

Comment: where is the file path you have put?

Comment: That's great! For the lazy user that just copy and paste: Replace the \ with / to get it working ;)