# I am creating a helper function for my custom package in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, package, laravel-8, php-8

Laravel 8, PHP 8.0

[here is helper function autoload array in package composer.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ogi1S.png)

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Chatify\\": "src/"
    },
    "files": [
        "src/helper.php"
    ]
},
```

But When I try to call helper by any of its function inside blade file or in the controller its did not detect it. Its only detect the Application helper file.

I have trid these command composer dumpautoload and composer update, but it did not help.

I am trying to create a helper function for my custom package. I dont want to use Laravel Application Helper Function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its Already Solved here

[Creating a custom helper in own package in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57636095/creating-a-custom-helper-in-own-package-in-laravel)

Could not solve it by composer independently and used my package service provider. I added this code to the boot() method of my FaviconServiceProvider and it works now:

```
if (File::exists(__DIR__ . '\app\helpers.php')) {
            require __DIR__ . '\app\helpers.php';
        }
```

Comment: If the question is already answered elsewhere on SO, it should normally be closed as a duplicate.  You should not just copy the answer and repost it.

Comment: It is not solved - this is a workaround.